# Stuck on wrong keyboard layout on LyX

Tags: lyx

I can't seem to write normal letters now inside a math equations, every letter of my keyboard now writes some weird symbols. I think I switched by accidentally using some CTRL+anykey type shortcut but I have no idea which was it.

Here are the symbols:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are writing letters in `\mathbb` font. After you type 'R', then press "Space" once to exit `mathbb` font but stay in the math mode. Then press `^` on your keyboard to start the exponent.

By the way, when figuring out problems like these, it's sometimes helpful to go to "View > Code Preview Pane". Then you can easily see which letters are inside `\mathbb{}` and which are outside.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its a problem only when writing powers of a set like R, Q..if I don't use those and write the power beforehand then I write it with normal letters, so I got around the problem by doing that.